# Embedded Font Not Displaying On Other Devices (AS3, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, adobe, font-embedding

So I've written a bit of code in Actionscript 3.0 that displays a string when you hover over a word on screen. The issue with this however is that when displayed on other devices such as a Windows desktop, the font reverts back to default. I've checked Adobe Animate and my fonts are all embedded correctly in the preferences so I'm assuming something is missing in my code which I've listed here:

```js
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.Font
import com.adobe.tvsdk.mediacore.TextFormat;

stop();

Previous3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Frame4_prev);

function Frame4_prev(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(3);
}

Next3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, Frame4_next);

function Frame4_next(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(5);
}



/* ---------- HOVER CHART WITH INFO ---------- */


/* MUCH_info (1) */

MUCH_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over1);
MUCH_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out1);
var fl_TF1:TextField;
var textformat1:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
var i1:int = 20;
var fl_TextToDisplay1:String = 

"My Utility Cabinet Holdings, LLC";

function over1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MUCH_info.visible = true;
    fl_TF1 = new TextField();
    fl_TF1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    fl_TF1.background = false;
    fl_TF1.border = false;
    fl_TF1.x = 125;
    fl_TF1.y = 643;
    fl_TF1.text = fl_TextToDisplay1;
    addChild(fl_TF1);
    
    textformat1.size = i1;
    textformat1.font = "Europa-Regular";
    fl_TF1.setTextFormat(textformat1);
}

function out1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_TF1.visible = false;
}


/* RealMTRX_info (2) */

RealMTRX_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over2);
RealMTRX_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out2);
var fl_TF2:TextField;
var textformat2:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
var i2:int = 21;
var fl_TextToDisplay2:String = 

"Specializes in tenant billing, sub-metering, and green initiatives";

function over2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    RealMTRX_info.visible = true;
    fl_TF2 = new TextField();
    fl_TF2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    fl_TF2.background = false;
    fl_TF2.border = false;
    fl_TF2.x = 125;
    fl_TF2.y = 643;
    fl_TF2.text = fl_TextToDisplay2;
    addChild(fl_TF2);
    
    textformat2.size = i2;
    textformat2.font = "Europa-Regular";
    fl_TF2.setTextFormat(textformat2);
}

function out2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_TF2.visible = false;
}


/* MUCSaaS_info (3) */

MUCSaaS_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over3);
MUCSaaS_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out3);
var fl_TF3:TextField;
var textformat3:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
var i3:int = 18;
var fl_TextToDisplay3:String = 

"An invoice management system able to track, centralize, and analyze billing data";

function over3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MUCSaaS_info.visible = true;
    fl_TF3 = new TextField();
    fl_TF3.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    fl_TF3.background = false;
    fl_TF3.border = false;
    fl_TF3.x = 90;
    fl_TF3.y = 643;
    fl_TF3.text = fl_TextToDisplay3;
    addChild(fl_TF3);
    
    textformat3.size = i3;
    textformat3.font = "Europa-Regular";
    fl_TF3.setTextFormat(textformat3);
}

function out3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_TF3.visible = false;
}


/* MagnaData_info (4) */

MagnaData_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over4);
MagnaData_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out4);
var fl_TF4:TextField;
var textformat4:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
var i4:int = 20;
var fl_TextToDisplay4:String = 

"Develops internal system design and updates, robotics, and data mining";

function over4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MagnaData_info.visible = true;
    fl_TF4 = new TextField();
    fl_TF4.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    fl_TF4.background = false;
    fl_TF4.border = false;
    fl_TF4.x = 90;
    fl_TF4.y = 643;
    fl_TF4.text = fl_TextToDisplay4;
    addChild(fl_TF4);
    
    textformat4.size = i4;
    textformat4.font = "EuropaRegular";
    fl_TF4.setTextFormat(textformat4);
}

function out4(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_TF4.visible = false;
}


/* GeoMAH_info (5) */

GeoMAH_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over5);
GeoMAH_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out5);
var fl_TF5:TextField;
var textformat5:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
var i5:int = 18;
var fl_TextToDisplay5:String = 

"Specializes in data trends and anomalies, cost efficiency, and client consultation";

function over5(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    GeoMAH_info.visible = true;
    fl_TF5 = new TextField();
    fl_TF5.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    fl_TF5.background = false;
    fl_TF5.border = false;
    fl_TF5.x = 90;
    fl_TF5.y = 643;
    fl_TF5.text = fl_TextToDisplay5;
    addChild(fl_TF5);
    
    textformat5.size = i5;
    textformat5.font = "EuropaRegular";
    fl_TF5.setTextFormat(textformat5);
}

function out5(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_TF5.visible = false;
}


/* SST_info (6) */

SST_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over6);
SST_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out6);
var fl_TF6:TextField;
var textformat6:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
var i6:int = 20;
var fl_TextToDisplay6:String = 

"Outside services that help maintain the MUC website";

function over6(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    SST_info.visible = true;
    fl_TF6 = new TextField();
    fl_TF6.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    fl_TF6.background = false;
    fl_TF6.border = false;
    fl_TF6.x = 100;
    fl_TF6.y = 643;
    fl_TF6.text = fl_TextToDisplay6;
    addChild(fl_TF6);
    
    textformat6.size = i6;
    textformat6.font = "Europa-Regular";
    fl_TF6.setTextFormat(textformat6);
}

function out6(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_TF6.visible = false;
}


/* Tamara_info (7) */

Tamara_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over7);
Tamara_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out7);
var fl_TF7:TextField;
var textformat7:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
var i7:int = 20;
var fl_TextToDisplay7:String = 

"Tamara Naser, President";

function over7(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Tamara_info.visible = true;
    fl_TF7 = new TextField();
    fl_TF7.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    fl_TF7.background = false;
    fl_TF7.border = false;
    fl_TF7.x = 125;
    fl_TF7.y = 643;
    fl_TF7.text = fl_TextToDisplay7;
    addChild(fl_TF7);
    
    textformat7.size = i7;
    textformat7.font = "Europa-Regular";
    fl_TF7.setTextFormat(textformat7);
}

function out7(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_TF7.visible = false;
}


/* DataEntry_info (8) */

DataEntry_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over8);
DataEntry_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out8);
var fl_TF8:TextField;
var textformat8:TextFormat = new TextFormat ();
var i8:int = 20;
var fl_TextToDisplay8:String = 

"Acquires, manages, and enters client invoice data";

function over8(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    DataEntry_info.visible = true;
    fl_TF8 = new TextField();
    fl_TF8.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    fl_TF8.background = false;
    fl_TF8.border = false;
    fl_TF8.x = 100;
    fl_TF8.y = 643;
    fl_TF8.text = fl_TextToDisplay8;
    addChild(fl_TF8);
    
    textformat8.size = i8;
    textformat8.font = "Europa-Regular";
    fl_TF8.setTextFormat(textformat8);
    
}

function out8(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_TF8.visible = false;
}


/* Control_info (9) */

Control_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over9);
Control_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out9);
var fl_TF9:TextField;
var textformat9:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
var i9:int = 20;
var fl_TextToDisplay9:String = 

"Ensures the integrity and quality of data";

function over9(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Control_info.visible = true;
    fl_TF9 = new TextField();
    fl_TF9.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    fl_TF9.background = false;
    fl_TF9.border = false;
    fl_TF9.x = 100;
    fl_TF9.y = 643;
    fl_TF9.text = fl_TextToDisplay9;
    addChild(fl_TF9);
    
    textformat9.size = i9;
    textformat9.font = "Europa-Regular";
    fl_TF9.setTextFormat(textformat9);
}

function out9(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_TF9.visible = false;
}


/* Finance_info (10) */

Finance_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over10);
Finance_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out10);
var fl_TF10:TextField;
var textformat10:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
var i10:int = 19;
var fl_TextToDisplay10:String = 

"Assesses, monitors, and plans the utilization of cash and financial services";

function over10(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Finance_info.visible = true;
    fl_TF10 = new TextField();
    fl_TF10.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    fl_TF10.background = false;
    fl_TF10.border = false;
    fl_TF10.x = 90;
    fl_TF10.y = 643;
    fl_TF10.text = fl_TextToDisplay10;
    addChild(fl_TF10);
    
    textformat10.size = i10;
    textformat10.font = "Europa-Regular";
    fl_TF10.setTextFormat(textformat10);
}

function out10(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_TF10.visible = false;
}


/* Admin_info (11) */

Admin_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over11);
Admin_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out11);
var fl_TF11:TextField;
var textformat11:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
var i11:int = 20;
var fl_TextToDisplay11:String = 

"Acquires and manages physical invoices and handles other projects";

function over11(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    HR_info.visible = true;
    fl_TF11 = new TextField();
    fl_TF11.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    fl_TF11.background = false;
    fl_TF11.border = false;
    fl_TF11.x = 100;
    fl_TF11.y = 643;
    fl_TF11.text = fl_TextToDisplay11;
    addChild(fl_TF11);
    
    textformat11.size = i11;
    textformat11.font = "Europa-Regular";
    fl_TF11.setTextFormat(textformat11);
}

function out11(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_TF11.visible = false;
}


/* HR_info (12) */

HR_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over12);
HR_info.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, out12);
var fl_TF12:TextField;
var textformat12:TextFormat = new TextFormat;
var i12:int = 20;
var fl_TextToDisplay12:String = 

"Manages hiring and onboarding of employees and employee relations";

function over12(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    HR_info.visible = true;
    fl_TF12 = new TextField();
    fl_TF12.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    fl_TF12.background = false;
    fl_TF12.border = false;
    fl_TF12.x = 100;
    fl_TF12.y = 643;
    fl_TF12.text = fl_TextToDisplay12;
    addChild(fl_TF12);
    
    textformat12.size = i12;
    textformat12.font = "Europa-Regular";
    fl_TF12.setTextFormat(textformat12);
}

function out12(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    fl_TF12.visible = false;
}
```

My end goal is to have the string that is displayed on the hover to display with the font Europa  Regular. Is this because the string isn't targeted? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if you embedded correctly in the preferences, you should set embedFonts properties true

```
fl_TF12.embedFonts = true
```

also you can change your embedded font with this script

```
fl_TF12.font = Font.enumerateFonts()[0].fontName;
```

Comment: Beautiful. I'll give this a shot, I didn't realize this was something I could put in the code thank you!